# Why does SSL/TLS MAC the Master Secret?

Tags: tls

At the end of the SSL handshake both the client and server send a MAC over all previous messages and the master secret. However, why do we need to MAC the master secret? The master secret is computed at both the client and server independently, and all prior messages are included in the MAC.

Comment: It doesn't MAC the master secret. It uses the master secret as a *key* for the PRF.

Comment: @cpast I see. Our lecture slides show that the master secret is MACed with all previous messages. Could that be a mistake?

Comment: If you mean the `Finished` message, the actual RFC says it consists of `PRF(master_secret, finished_label, Hash(handshake_messages))` (the TLS PRF syntax is `PRF(secret, seed, data)`, and is essentially `HMAC(secret, seed || data)`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is based on a false premise (see @cpast's comment).